# M3G Plugins for Blender 2.59

Tags: python, java-me, blender, blender-2.50, m3g

I am looking for M3G plugins for Blender. I have already followed the link http://www.nelson-games.de/bl2m3g/ and installed Python v2.6.2 & Blender v2.4.9, but when it's not working. I have already asked this on Blender community but got no response yet.

If there are any plugins available of M3G for Blender 2.5, please do tell me.